# Convert to factor and then display in a custom order on graph

Tags: r, forcats

I have a character column in the following data frame. I would like to change it to factor in such a way that when I use ggplot to plot results, the labels on my x-axis come in a specific order:

```
  df <-  structure(list(Level = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1"
), Variable = c("lskill_wc", "Grande_Estab", "lskill_wc", "lskill_bc", 
"hskill_wc", "balcadv", "hskill_bc", "Vinculos_Micro"), estimate = c(0.154462929180099, 
-0.00565989816383741, 0.127039272664461, 0.244657086455149, 0.153358091697942, 
-0.00769107968294057, -0.00592547333520778, 0.138216262540319
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I want to change the first two columns to factors, recode them and change their order:

```
  Level Correspondence
  <chr> <chr>         
1 1     A         
2 2     B    

  Variable       Correspondence         
  <chr>          <chr>                  
1 lskill_wc      Low skill white collar     
2 lskill_bc      Low skill blue collar  
3 hskill_bc      High skill white collar
4 Grande_Estab   Large firm                       
5 Vinculos_Micro Employment
6 balcadv        Comp. Adv
```

The order to be shown on a graph would be the labels given according to the one in each `Correspondence` column.

Comment: Adding ```Variable = as.factor(c(....))``` will change "Variable" to a factor.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah I want to actually use ggplot to make a point graph. I would like to have variables with different values in ```Level``` to have different shapes. I also want to have them displayed in a specific order, given by the second column of the second data frame posted in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have completely changed the question, my original answer has become invalidated. I have been compelled to change it to avoid attracting downvotes.

It is probably better to ask a new question in this situation.

The answer is in exactly the same format as the original; you seem to just be getting mixed up about your factor levels. Your list of desired ordering of factors actually misses one out - "High skill blue collar worker"

```r
labels <- c( "Comp. Adv", "Large firm", "High skill blue collar worker", 
             "High skill white collar worker", "Low skill blue collar worker",
             "Low skill white collar worker", "Employment")
df$label <- as.factor(df$Variable)
levels(df$label) <- labels
df$label <- factor(df$label, labels[c(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 1)])
df
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   Level Variable       estimate label                         
#>   <chr> <chr>             <dbl> <fct>                         
#> 1 1     lskill_wc       0.154   Low skill white collar worker 
#> 2 1     Grande_Estab   -0.00566 Large firm                    
#> 3 1     lskill_wc       0.127   Low skill white collar worker 
#> 4 1     lskill_bc       0.245   Low skill blue collar worker  
#> 5 1     hskill_wc       0.153   High skill white collar worker
#> 6 2     balcadv        -0.00769 Comp. Adv                     
#> 7 1     hskill_bc      -0.00593 High skill blue collar worker 
#> 8 1     Vinculos_Micro  0.138   Employment  

levels(df$label)
#> [1] "Low skill white collar worker"  "Low skill blue collar worker"  
#> [3] "High skill white collar worker" "High skill blue collar worker" 
#> [5] "Large firm"                     "Employment"                    
#> [7] "Comp. Adv"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I am not actually sure what is happening. It seems to me the code is mixing up my values. I am going to change the question by posting my real data set