# R - ggplot with two Y axis's

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to make a plot with two Y axises with "tot_num_of_rides" in the first Y axis and "avg_temp" in the second Y axis. Here is my code,

```
monthly_trend <- read_csv("monthly_trend.csv")
monthly_trend$month <- month.abb[monthly_trend$month]

ggplot(data = monthly_trend) + 
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = month, y = tot_num_of_rides)) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = month, y = avg_temp*32000)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "month") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "num_of_rides", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./32000, name = "avg_temp"))
```

My data frame is as below,

```
head(monthly_trend)

# A tibble: 6 × 8
   year month num_of_rides_casual num_of_rides_member tot_num_of_rides perc_casual perc_member avg_temp
  <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>               <dbl>            <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>
1  2020 Sep                230072              300754           530826        43.3        56.7       20
2  2020 Oct                144529              242213           386742        37.4        62.6       14
3  2020 Nov                 87911              170940           258851        34.0        66.0        7
4  2020 Dec                 29997              101142           131139        22.9        77.1        0
5  2021 Jan                 18117               78715            96832        18.7        81.3       -3
6  2021 Feb                 10131               39491            49622        20.4        79.6       -1
```

However, I get the following error message,

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I would highly appreciate if someone could help me on the above.
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Try with `scale_x_discrete` as you month column is a character.

Comment: Hi Stefan, thanks for your quick response. As month name as a character,  does not come in x axis in monthly order (Sep to Aug) , I would like to convert the month data type to date format from character.  Will you be able to help me on this?

Comment: Ordering of labels is a separate question, that has been frequently answered e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516287/convert-to-factor-and-then-display-in-a-custom-order-on-graph

Answer (score -1):

```
library(tidyverse)
monthly_trend = read.table(
  header = TRUE,text="
year month num_of_rides_casual num_of_rides_member tot_num_of_rides perc_casual perc_member avg_temp
2020 Sep                230072              300754           530826        43.3        56.7       20
2020 Oct                144529              242213           386742        37.4        62.6       14
2020 Nov                 87911              170940           258851        34.0        66.0        7
2020 Dec                 29997              101142           131139        22.9        77.1        0
2021 Jan                 18117               78715            96832        18.7        81.3       -3
2021 Feb                 10131               39491            49622        20.4        79.6       -1  
2021 Mar                 18117               78715            296832        18.7        81.3       -3
2021 Apr                 10131               39491            249622        20.4        79.6       -1  
2021 May                 18117               78715            396832        18.7        81.3       -3
2021 Jun                 310131               39491            149622        20.4        79.6       -2  
2021 Jul                 310131               39491            149622        20.4        79.6       -1  
2021 Aug                 210131               39491            349622        20.4        79.6       10  
2021 Sep                 110131               39491            249622        20.4        79.6       12  
2021 Oct                 115131               39491            149622        20.4        79.6       5  
2021 Nov                 210131               39491            349622        20.4        79.6       22  
2021 Dec                 210131               39491            249622        20.4        79.6       8  
  ") %>%
  as_tibble()

months = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun", "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
monthly_trend = monthly_trend %>% 
  mutate(
    year = year %>% factor(),
    month = month %>% factor(months)
  )

monthly_trend %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.numeric(month), tot_num_of_rides, fill=year, color=year)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=avg_temp*32000)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "month", breaks = 1:12, labels = months) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "num_of_rides", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./32000, name = "avg_temp"))
```

[image]

Was that what you meant?